# xlrd read number as string

Tags: python, xlrd

I am trying to read from an xls file a long number (6425871003976) but python keeps trunking it before it reads it as a number not a string (6.42587100398e+12). Is there any method to read it directly as a string even thou in the xls file it is a number?

```
values = sheet.row_values(rownum)
```

in values it appears correctly (6425871003976.0) but when I try values[0] it is already switched to the incorrect value.

**Solution:**

This was my solution using repr():

```
if type(values[1]) is float:  
    code_str = repr(values[1]).split(".")[0]
else:
    code_str = values[1]
product_code = code_str.strip(' \t\n\r')
```

Comment: how does the number appear in the excel sheet ? it appears like 6.42587100398e+12(string) or 6425871003976(int). an you please also add your work to the question.

Comment: the number appears like 6.42587100398e+12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same value. All that's different is how the value is being printed to screen. The scientific notation you get is because to print the number `str` is called on it. When you print the list of values the internal `__str__` method of the list calls `repr` on each of its elements. Try `print(repr(values[0]))` instead.

Answer (score 2):

use `print "%d" %(values[0])`

%d is used for printing integer values

Answer (score 1):

This is an example, which bring the value of a cell (in your case it's an int), you need to convert it to a string using the str function

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='xls.xlsx', read_only=True)
ws = wb['Sheet1']
for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        cell_str=str(cell.value)
```